# Jquery traversing up instead of down

Tags: jquery

I have a bootstrap dropdown that I am trying to populate I guess you would call header with the value, kind of like you would see on a regular html dropdown. So the user knows what they selected in the menu.

My issue is that if you have more than one drop down on a page the jquery will target them both and not just the one I'm selecting from. Normally I would fix this by adding a `$(this).parent()`, but the html is a bit more complex and I really rather not do a chain of 
`.parent().parent().parent()`

There must be a better way of doing this that I'm missing or just plain forgetting.

my html looks like

```
<p><label class="control-label" data-bind="html: label"></label></p>
<div class="dropdown" data-bind="cssProperties: properties, css: { hidden : EvalDisplay() == false }">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle col-md-12 dropBtn" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class='pull-left'  data-bind="value: value,attr: { 'name' : id}"></span>
        <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
        <p class='clearfix'></p>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu side-dropdown" role="menu">
        <!-- ko foreach: options -->
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-bind="html: Value"></a></li>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
    <p class='clearfix'></p>
</div>
```

and my jQuery looks like this

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    $(".dropBtn.btn:first-child").html('<span class="pull-left">'+$(this).text()+'</span><span class="caret pull-right"></span>');
    $(".dropBtn.btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
});
```

and a jsfiddle to play with 
http://jsfiddle.net/0p1Lhzq0/

I have been playing with `parentsUtil()` as well, but that just doesn't seem right.

Any help would be wonderful!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the `.parent()` chain?

Comment: I really just want to avoid a massive string of .parent()'s

Comment: usually this is done using `.closest()`.

Comment: @Barmar, I was trying something with closest, but if my memory is right (it's getting late so this could very well not be right) closest goes down to the closest element and not up.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0p1Lhzq0/1/ This what you're trying to do?

Comment: No, your memory is wrong. `.closest()` goes up, `.find()` goes down.

Comment: @CullenJ, no...I need the value inside the drop don when you select it...not changing the values of the dropdowns.

Comment: @Barmar So it would be $(this).closest('.dropBtn.btn:first-child').html()?

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/0p1Lhzq0/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.btn:first-child').html('<span class="pull-left">'+$(this).text()+'</span><span class="caret pull-right"></span>').val($(this).text());
});
```

[Corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/0p1Lhzq0/7/)

Comment: That doesn't seem to want to work in the fiddle though... http://jsfiddle.net/0p1Lhzq0/2/

Comment: it should be `.dropdown`, not `.dropBtn`, since `.dropBtn` is not an ancestor of `li a`.